# Does printf alter variables?

Tags: c, printf, increment

I am not sure if incrementing a variable within a printf statement saves the valuable to a variable or not.

```
int x = 0;

printf("x=%d\n", ++x);
printf("x=%d\n", x);
```

Would the output be

```
x=1
x=0
```

or

```
x=1
x=1
```

I never learned the basics of C and want to know how it matches up to C++.

I do understand the pre/post increment but I am worried that doing ++x inside the first printf() won't save if I am incrementing it in the scope of a function.

Comment: What prevents you from running your code?

Comment: `operator++` modifies values. That is the point of it.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `printf`. In C, all variables are passed by value. Since you're not taking an address-of (`&`) anywhere, there's no way `printf` can modify your variables.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I am unable to play with any code at the moment. Was just wondering

Comment: Either Pre or Post, the increment is always done. Hence the Answer is x=1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output will be 1.

Your expression `++x` will be

```
x = x+1;
```

In both the `printf()` you get `1`

So the value of x is modified with the pre-increment operator here and in `printf()` in the second line prints the new value of x which is `1`

`printf()` just prints the value of `x` it doesn't modify your variable

Note the difference between pre-increment and post-increment .

With post-increment you will get `0` in the first printf() because the value of `x` is fetched by the `printf()'s` `%d` and later `x` gets incremented leading to the value of `x` in the second prinf() to be `1`

Answer (score 4):

The pre/post-increment operators always modify the value of their operand.

```
 int main(int argc, char **argv) {
     int x = 0;

     printf("x=%d\n", ++x);
     printf("x=%d\n", x);
 }

 char@char:~$ ./a.out
 x=1
 x=1
```

As somebody else pointed out, the post-increment operator will return 0 in this case...

```
 int main(int argc, char **argv) {
     int x = 0;

     printf("x=%d\n", x++);
     printf("x=%d\n", x);
 }

 char@char:~$ ./a.out
 x=0
 x=1
```

but the value of x will still be modified.

To get your expected output, replace **++x** with **x+1**.

Answer (score 1):

Incrementing the value in the variable is not based on a printf statement. It will
done by the increment or decrement operator. so the work of increment operator is
increment the value by one.

so it does the work.

```
Output of this would be 
x=1
x=1
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not printf that changes x, it's that a C expression can have side effects. Just like a C++ expression.

++x increments x then returns that value.
x++ returns the value of x then increments x.

So the output here is

```
x=1
x=1
```

but for `x++` it would be

```
x=0
x=1
```

Answer (score 1):

The `printf` family itself doesn't modify variables (memory corruption notwithstanding) but the *expression* `++x` *will,* the effect of which is to increment `x` then use that incremented value as the result of the expression.

But that has nothing to do with `printf`, the expression is just being evaluated so it can be *passed* into `printf`.

So you'll see `1 1` rather than `1 0`.